# Close jQuery Popup when ESC KEY Pressed on the particular instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code which am used for closing the popup using ESC Key

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e){
     if (e.keyCode === 27) {
         closePopup(id);
     }
 });
```

Later, i found that was wrong, wrong in the sense, i have written the above code in .ready(), that is whenever i pressed the ESC Key it makes some process so, i changed to the following code, This seems good but whenever i hover only the action takes place

```
$("#"+id).hover(function() {
         $(document).keyup(function(e){
             if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                 closePopup(id);
             }
         });
     });
```

Now what i need is, i need to close the popup using ESC KEY ONLY when the popup opens.
Can anyone help..?

i dont want to use document for this..!!

Comment: id seems undefined in $("#"+id)

Comment: Providing a jsfiddle could help you in order to get some answer

Comment: ya,ofcourse it should be undefined, i need a link to catch when the popup opens

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Deleted older answer misunderstand something, there is nothing bad at your first try. at first i though you are trying with an input now i read a gain its (modal, sorry about that

So

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { <DO YOUR WORK HERE> }   // esc
});
```

To `unbind` use

```
 $(document).unbind("keyup", keyUpFunc)......
```

Comment: i have tried, when i clicks ESC KEY no alert came, that means not going inside to bind $("#"+id).bind('keyup', function(e){ alert("test")